# twitter bootstrap popover plugin bug - this.isHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I copied the example straight from their page:

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/631/

... and I get the following error:

```
this.isHTML is not a function
[Break On This Error]       
$tip.find('.popover-title')[this.isHTML(title) ? 'html' : 'text'](title)
```

Any thoughts?

Here's the order in which I'm importing the JS files:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/date.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../Scripts/lib/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `bootstrap-tooltip.js` before `bootstrap-popover.js` and it will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyN9H/

Thats because `popover` extends BOOTSTRAP-TOOLTIP.js.

Comment: Strange.  I thought I was doing that in my actual site.  I'll have to go back and double check.

Comment: @Adam Levitt what was the solution?

Comment: The problem was that I was using version 2.0.2 of the tooltip.js library.  Crazy!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem and was using bootstrap-tooltip v 2.0.2 instead of the newer v 2.0.4. Upgrading to 2.0.4 did the trick. Thanks Adam.